# Retrieve back navigation action from react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigation, back-button, react-router

In the application I'm building I chose react-router to handle the navigation flow, but I need to track the event of navigating back on the browser, so when you try to load the component in the new render I need to know if the user has landed here by pressing the back button.
What would be the best way to track it? I'm pretty sure that is using the History API, but couldn't find any straight way to check that, and it feels like it should be pretty easy given how the library works.

Anyone that could shed some light on the matter would be very welcomed! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're correct! React-Router uses the HTML5 History API, this is explained in the docs here (https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#histories) you'll need to import the 'Browser History' package and pass it into your router, documented here (https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md#browserhistory).

There is an example in the doc's how to go about implementing it all here (https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md#example-implementation)

Comment: Thank you @Stefano, I appreciate, but I already got that far with the documentation :) The problem comes right after, when I try to know weather my render comes from a browser back action or not. The history object that goes through render view objects is not documented anywhere that I could find. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing out the box that will detect this, you will have to listen to route changes and build up a stack. Each time the event happens you'll need to examine the stack to detect if it was a forwards or backwards navigation. It's quite tricky to implement, but this is where you can do it:

```
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

let pathStack = [];
browserHistory.listen(function(ev) {
  pathStack.unshift(ev.pathname);

  console.log('Do something clever with:', pathStack);
});

<Router history={browserHistory}>{routes}</Router>
```

Comment: Yay! Thank you @Dominic, that does the job! Feels a little bit hacky though, since there is a whole library handling the navigation flow. I can't believe same stack is not natively implemented on the history object that is passed through the app views renders. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Sorry @Dominic, I thought that would do the job, but actually it doesn't. Any repetition of natural click navigation would look as a back move. You can use ev.action, as back, forward and refresh come with 'POP', but again you can't really make a difference between forwards and backwards navigation, it would look the same for the stack checking logic.

Comment: Yep I'm not sure if there's a way of differentiating nicely (apart from checking if the route change came from a link or something)